# How to get maximum accuracy of user's current location

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am using this code to get the accurate user's location...

```
watchID=navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(handleGetCurrentPosition, handleGetCurrentPositionError, {enableHighAccuracy:true});

function handleGetCurrentPosition(location)
{   
    document.getElementById("lat").value = location.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("lon").value = location.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("accu").value =location.coords.accuracy;
    document.forms["myform"].submit();
}

function handleGetCurrentPositionError(){
    alert("Location could not be found.")
}
```

bt the result i am getting is not accurate.
Is there any problem the code i am using?

Comment: What is your definition of "accurate"?

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy depends on capabilities of your `Geolocation` device. `navigator.geolocation` is just an `API` which works with that device. If the device does not support high accuracies, you can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

this the below code to get accurate location. i have written this code in HTML 5.

1. Create a map placeholder in html document.

< output id="mapToYou" >Searching for your current location...< /output >

1. Call this js script in page load.

```
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        } else {
            error('not supported');
        }
    },false);

    function success(position) {
        var mapToYou = document.querySelector('#mapToYou');
        alert("Gotcha!");
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
        var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: latlng,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var googleMap = new google.maps.Map(mapToYou, myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng, 
          map: googleMap, 
          title:"You are here!"
        });
    }

    function error(msg) {
        var mapToYou = document.querySelector('#mapToYou');
        mapToYou.innerHTML = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "failed";
        mapToYou.className = 'fail';

        // console.log(arguments);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Google's location api's?

If not, here is the link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Actually there are a lot of on-going APIs that are developed by Google to increase the accuracy of location finding

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful link at : http://www.geoplugin.com , provides a very good location filtering API and has really scary precision at predicting user location.

Here is an example of how this is to be used: http://www.jquery4u.com/api-calls/geo-location-2-lines-javascript/#.T_QZrxdo3IU

Comment: It does provide all the attributes of location including Lat and Long. Kindly check the example I have provided it has all the methods required for you to accurately get the information you need.